# Python pandas preserving decimal commas in the output csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, number-formatting

I'm using pandas library to do some operations on `.csv` file.

Input file `input.csv`:

```
    A    B   
   1,2  2,2
   3,5  5,4
```

My code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = read_csv('input.csv', sep = ';', encoding = 'ANSI', decimal = ',')
'''
some operations on cells like adding, multiplying...  
'''

df.to_csv('output.csv', sep = ';', encoding = 'ANSI', index = False)
```

And here is how my `output.csv` looks like:

```
    A    B    C   
   1.2  2.2  6.5
   3.5  5.4  7.8
```

But is there any way to keep my decimal separator as comma like there was in the `input.csv`?

Here is how `output.csv` should look like:

```
    A    B    C   
   1,2  2,2  6,5
   3,5  5,4  7,8
```

I have tried something like this but it didn't work:

```
df = df.astype(str).replace('.',',')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Method 1**

You can use:

```
df.to_csv('output.csv', sep = ';', encoding='ANSI', index=False, decimal=",")
```

**Method 2**

As an alternative you can also use.

```
df = df.applymap(lambda x: str(x).replace('.',','))
```

instead of `df = df.astype(str).replace('.',',')`

It would give:

```
      A   B   C
0   1,2 2,2 6,5
1   3,5 5,4 7,8
```

And then

```
df.to_csv('output.csv', sep = ';', encoding = 'ANSI', index=False)
```

Comment: This is a built-in feature to [`DataFrame.to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html). If it's not working for you there is likely an underlying reason (e.g., outdated version of Pandas, your types are actually strings and not floats, etc.) that you should diagnose

Comment: You should add a note about the `decimal` argument to your answer so that others looking to solve this problem are aware of the built-in option, in case their dataset is too big to loop over every element.

Comment: @sundance, sounds like a god bit. Answer edited. Thanks.

Comment: I have pandas v0.23.3, except floats I store in my `.csv` files a few strings if that's the case.

Answer (score 2):

Like `pandas.read_csv`, [DataFrame.to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) also has a `decimal` argument:

```
df.to_csv('output.csv', sep = ';', encoding='ANSI', index=False, decimal=",")
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me, I'm still having dots in my `output.csv`

Comment: Works fine on my machine. What version of Python and Pandas are you running?